# Apache web server giving 404 when trying to deploy Flask on it

Tags: python, apache, flask, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to deploy my flask application on a Windows Server 2012. I'm following the instructions here to the point: https://claudiosparpaglione.wordpress.com/2013/03/06/how-to-deploy-flask-applications-to-apache-webserver/

Now, this is my apache config file (relevant bits):

```
Listen 5060
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
<Directory C:/FlaskOnApache>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
WSGIScriptAlias /api C:/FlaskOnApache/flasky.wsgi
```

When I go to:

```
http://localhost:5060/
```

I get the "It works!" page.

But when I go to `http://localhost:5060/api/hello?name=claudio` I get a 404.

What am I doing wrong?

Error.log gives me this:

> Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat:
>   C:/FlaskOnApache/flasky.wsgi

But it is definitely present there and is the copy of what is mentioned in the link above.

Edit:

My flasky.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello')
def hello_world():
    name = request.args.get('name','')
    return 'Hello ' + name + '!'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My flasky.wsgi.py file:

```
import sys

#Expand Python classes path with your app's path
sys.path.insert(0, "C:/FlaskOnApache")

from flasky import app

#Put logging code (and imports) here ...

#Initialize WSGI app object
application = app
```

Answer (score 0):

in your Flask app.py you need to edit route from:  `@app.route('/')`
to:

```
`@app.route('/hello')
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake. Got it working. The file name is supposed to be "flasky.wsgi" not "flasky.wsgi.py". Thanks guys!